# how to `sudo su postgres` on a remote server with a script

Tags: linux, postgresql, shell, ssh

I am sure this question would have come up thousands of time but I still cant find the answer or perhaps I am too dumb for it. here it is.
I am trying to ssh a server and then take the postgresql database backup. I tried this.

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh admin@myserver 'NOW=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y"); cd /home/open/backup; sudo su postgres; pg_dump v2 > v2-$NOW.sql;'
```

The problem  think is that when I do `sudo su postgres` it asks for a password and their it gets stuck. any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Can't you ssh directly to the `postgres` remote user?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit `/etc/sudoers` to allow the user admin to run commands as postgres without password:

```
admin ALL=(postgres) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

You could also narrow it down to specific commands rather than ALL if you prefer.